# JQuery can I escape Plain Object keys?

Tags: jquery, json, object

I used `$.getJSON()` to get data from a json api. It returns a Plain Object. I tried to get a specific value from the object like this: `data.topartists.artist[0].image[4].#text`. This causes an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` because of the `#`. Is there any way to escape the `#` so that I can get a value from the key `#text`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use bracket notation

```
data.topartists.artist[0].image[4]['#text']
```